# Benefits of Thread Joining

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

What are the benefits of thread joining ? If the point is to join a thread to stop a thread A until thread B is finished executing, for instance (B.join()) why not use a global variable to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `join()` allows A to go to sleep and not consume CPU time until B ends, and it also ensures that B has completely ended before continuing with A. In general it's just far more efficient. It also avoids the hassle of creating an additional variable.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason you want to call `pthread_join()` or `pthread_detach()` to thread that was created with flag `PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE` is: the system can reclaim all resources associated with the thread after thread termination. Failure to join to or detach joinable threads causes memory and other resource leaks until the process ends.

Comment: There is nothing similar `pthread_detach()` in java. Does this mean we should always use `join()`? Not using `join()` means jvm will not release resources? When a thread terminates without joining does jvm release `ReentrantLock`s?  Does it remove thread local storage(`ThreadLocal<T>`) automatically?